# Regex to filter out everything but a certain date

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I create a javascript function which would filter out everything but a certain date in DD.MM.YYYY format?

Example:

```
08.03.2012.
četvrtak, 8.3.2012. 14:25
Četvrtak, 08.03.2012 22:19
08.03.2012 13:13
08.03.2012 / 20:04
08.03.2012., 20:41
08.03.2012 19:02
```

everyone of these needs to return `08.03.2012`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually could be better :)

```
/\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}\b/
```

Comment: Yep, better. Added word boundaries so it won't match numbers that happen to be substrings of other data.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3091v)

But this is checking only the format, not if this is a valid Date!

`\b` is a word boundary to avoid partial matches

`\d` is a digit

`{n,m}` is a quantifier, requiring a min of n and a max of m